# Help with Markov chain involving matrix diagonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, diagonalization

I am currently trying to solve this question from a sample test for my linear algebra course:

> After exposure to certain live pathogens, the body develops long-term immunity. The
>   evolution over time of the associated disease can be modeled as a dynamical system whose
>   state vector at time ***t*** consists of the number of people who have not been exposed and are
>   therefore susceptible, the number who are currently sick with the disease, and the number
>   who have recovered and are now immune. Suppose that the associated yearly **3 x 3**
>   transition matrix has eigenvalues **λ = 1, 1/2, 0**, and that the eigenvectors  corresponding to the first two eigenvalues are and **x1 = (60, 20, 30) and x2 = (-60, -30, -90)**  respectively. The
>   initial state vector for the population is given by
>   **v0 = 500*x1 + 200*x2 + 100*x3**
>   where the third eigenvector **x3** is not given here. How many people will be sick with the
>   disease **2 years** later?

I know that the probability vector at time **t** will be **p(t) = T^t * p0** where **T** is the transition matrix and **p0** is the initial probability vector.

Since I have been given two eigenvectors and three eigenvalues of the **3 x 3** transition matrix, I thought I could determine **T^t** by using diagonalisation: **T^t = P* D^t * P^-1**

However, the problem I have is not knowing the third eigenvector of **T**. This is what I think I have deduced so far:

**T**

\begin{bmatrix}60&-60&a\\20&-30&b\\30&-90&c\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1/2&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}60&-60&a\\20&-30&b\\30&-90&c\end{bmatrix}^-1

How do I go about finding T without the third eigenvector using this approach? Is this the right approach for the question?

Answer (score 1):

The third eigenvector does not matter, since the associated eigenvalue is $0$. You don’t need the explicit formula for T, it suffices to write that
$$T x_1 = 1* x_1$$

$$T x_2 = \frac{1}{2} x_2$$

$$T x_3 = 0 * x_3$$

And by linearity of T,

$$T^t v_0 = 1^t *500* x_1 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^t * 200* x_2 + 0 ^t*100* x_3 $$

Which gives the result $t$ years later.

Comment: How did you arrive at that equation?

Comment: Added more detail